# How do I do this data transformation most efficiently

Tags: python, csv, data-manipulation

I have one really big CSV file with the following structure:

```
user_id,mail_id,action
1,100,sent
1,100,opened
1,100,clicked
2,100,sent
2,101,sent
```

I want to reformat it to create a new CSV file that has one row for each user_id and 1 column for each mail_id.  The value in each cell should be blank if there is not a corresponding row in the original table.  Otherwise it will have the latest action that corresponds with that user and mail_id (clicked comes after opened, which comes after sent).

The final product (given the small data table above) should look like this:

```
user_id,100,101
1,clicked,NULL
2,sent,sent
```

This data manipulation is fairly straightforward, but the original CSV is quite long, and I am looking for tips on how to do this most efficiently.

Comment: Is the CSV sorted?

Comment: yes, it is sorted.  And I can easily have it sorted by any of the columns (or by a combination of columns).

Answer (score 0):

Time complexity to read data into some structure is O(m*n) for m rows, n columns, regardless of the method used to read the data. Easiest to read data into a dictionary-of-dictionaries, `{user_id: {100: most_recent_action,101: None}...}`, using `csv.read` and then iterate over the dictionary-of-dictionaries outputting to some csv with `csv.write`.